# Selenium verify text or link on the web page

Tags: selenium, selenium-rc

If i have to check a 'xyz' text present in header of the web page & the 'xyz' is present in body of the page.on the use of this function.it will return true ,which is not correct..

*selenium.isTextPresent("xyz");*

Same question for link presence check.

*selenium.isLinkPresent("link=xyz");*

Please suggest me what is the best way to verify the text/link on the page through selenium.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use XPath to narrow down your search. For e.g. if you have XML like

```
 <MyXmlDoc>
    <Header>
        <TextNode>Hello World</TextNode>
        <A href="http://www.google.com"">Google</A>
    </Header>

    <Body>
        <TextNode>Hello World</TextNode>
        <A href="http://www.google.com"">Google</A>
    </Body>
 </MyXmlDoc>
```

To check if text `Hello World` is present in the `<Header>` you can use
`selenium.isElementPresent("//Header/TextNode[.='Hello World']");`  
OR 
To check if text `Hello World` is present in the `<Body>` you can use
`selenium.isElementPresent("//Body/TextNode[.='Hello World']");`

Similarly goes for `Anchor (<A>)` for `<A>` in `<Header>`
`selenium.isElementPresent("//Header/A[.='Google']");` 
 
And

for `<A>` in `<Body>`
`selenium.isElementPresent("//Body/A[.='Google']");`

Hope this helps

Comment: So Vaman, the xpath is the best way to locate any element. is there any formula to get/create xpath of any web element ? In the same manner any trick, formula or tool to get CSS and DOM locator. Thanks again.

Comment: There are tools available that gives you the XPath of an element. But note that they give absolute XPath. As a programmer you need relative XPaths which are not provided by any tool as far as I know. There is a nice tutorial on XPaths [here](http://zvon.org/comp/m/xpath.html) which will help you understand XPaths more deeply.